# Adding text at the end of each new line

Tags: php, html, newline, jtextarea

I trying to to get a break to show up at the end of each new line in a text block. I'm then echoing the block and need it to actually say "`<br />`" at the end of each line as I'm making a code generator that this will get copied and pasted into another html page, so I need it actually say "`<br />`". I've tried using the nl2br function which adds the break, but it gets registered by the browser, not printed.

So this is what the flow would look like. Somebody enters this text into a multi-line input:

```
This is an example
This is an example
This is an example
This is an example
```

And after the submit, the php would feed me this:

```
This is an example<br />
This is an example<br />
This is an example<br />
This is an example<br />
```

Is there a function that can do this? (echo ?($posted_info);)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display the actual html you need to use [htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) like this:

`echo htmlentities(nl2br("This is an example \r\n"));`

which will convert it to:

`This is an example&lt;br /&gt;`

The output visible on the browser will be:

`This is an example<br />`

In your case use this:

`echo htmlentities(nl2br($posted_info));`

Answer (score 1):

You should use PHPs [nl2br()](http://php.net/function.nl2br.php) function.